# How can I fix C2509 member function not declared in 'SimpleApp'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, chromium-embedded

I am stuck on expanding the SimpleApp from the chromium embedded framework 3.2704.1416 and cannot get my head around it : (

I try to add the `pepflashplayer.dll` locally to prevent version mismatch with system-wide installed dlls, so I need to add some command line switches by implementing [`CefApp:OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing`](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/include/cef_app.h?at=2704&fileviewer=file-view-default#cef_app.h-160). So far I based my code on examples from the web and the [implementation](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/654931637cb04c2f404b7ee1b0dc8e2f4f4cc1bb/tests/cefsimple/simple_app.cc?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#simple_app.cc-59) of [`CefBrowserProcessHandler::OnContextInitialized`](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/654931637cb04c2f404b7ee1b0dc8e2f4f4cc1bb/include/cef_browser_process_handler.h?at=2704&fileviewer=file-view-default#cef_browser_process_handler.h-58) within the same example project.

In file simple_app.h I added the declaration of OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing:

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Embedded Framework Authors. All rights
// reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that
// can be found in the LICENSE file.

#ifndef CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_SIMPLE_APP_H_
#define CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_SIMPLE_APP_H_

#include "include/cef_app.h"

// Implement application-level callbacks for the browser process.
class SimpleApp : public CefApp,
                  public CefBrowserProcessHandler {
 public:
  SimpleApp();

  // CefApp methods:
  virtual void OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing(const CefString &process_type,
                                             CefRefPtr<CefCommandLine> command_line)
      OVERRIDE;
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefBrowserProcessHandler> GetBrowserProcessHandler()
      OVERRIDE { return this; }

  // CefBrowserProcessHandler methods:
  virtual void OnContextInitialized() OVERRIDE;

 private:
  // Include the default reference counting implementation.
  IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(SimpleApp);
};

#endif  // CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_SIMPLE_APP_H_
```

In file simple_app.cc I added the body of the new function according to the implementation of `SimpleApp::OnContextInitialized`:

```
void SimpleApp::OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing(const CefString& process_type,
                                              CefRefPtr<CefCommandLine> command_line) {
  command_line->AppendSwitchWithValue(CefString("ppapi-flash-path"),
                                      CefString("pepflashplayer32_21_0_0_242.dll"));
  command_line->AppendSwitchWithValue(CefString("ppapi-flash-version"), 
                                      CefString("21.0.0.242"));
#ifdef NDEBUG
  command_line->AppendSwitchWithValue(CefString("log-severity"), CefString("disabled"));
#endif
}

void SimpleApp::OnContextInitialized() {
  CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

// [...]
}
```

Yet, this does not compile and I do not understand why, my background with c++ is not deep enough. Intellisense (VSc++ 2013) underlines simple_app.cc:17(OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing) with "Ein vererbter Member ist nicht zulässig" ("inherited member is not allowed"). If I try to compile it I get "C2509: 'OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing': Memberfunktion wurde in 'SimpleApp' nicht deklariert" ("member function not declared in 'SimpleApp'")

Comment: is it possible that you have two simple_app.h, and are looking at the wrong one in another directory?

Comment: @KarstenKoop Great catch! This is a copy of the cefsimple and I missed the #include statement... it included the original header. It now works nicely, thank you.